# Bus between Cannon Beach, Oregon and Oswald West State Park

Tags: usa, public-transport, buses, oregon

Google maps show [this route](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Midtown,+Cannon+Beach,+OR/Short+Sands+Trail+-+North+Trailhead/@45.8258614,-124.0252501,12z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x5494a4dfbfeef503:0x1336b90cc5493f1f!2m2!1d-123.9618428!2d45.889497!1m5!1m1!1s0x0:0xa0fc3912563a69de!2m2!1d-123.9578665!2d45.7615145!3e3) but I can't see any bus stops in Oswald West State Park  in the street view. The [website](https://www.nworegontransit.org/routes/tillamook_-_manzanita_-_cannon_beach/) of the organization that runs this bus also doesn't list any stops between Manzanita and Midtown Cannon Beach:

[image]

So will the driver drop me off wherever I want? And where am I supposed to catch this bus when going from Oswald West State Park to Cannon Beach if there are no official stops?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you download the pdf schedule at the link you provided, you will see three bits of 'rider info' that are applicable:

> - When flagging a bus along the route, choose a
>   safe location where the bus driver can easily
>   see you, can safely pull off road and where you
>   are not at risk from other vehicles.

Ok, so you can flag the bus, you don't have to get it at an official stop.

> - Signal bus with a two-handed wave. Check the
>   destination sign to ensure proper bus.

Be obvious when flagging it, a subtle gesture isn't going to attract attention.

> - Let driver know where you will be stopping, or
>   when available, pull the stop cord near your
>   seat prior to your requested stop.

Similarly, you can get off between 'official' stops, but let the driver know you are going to do so reasonably early.

As an addition, I will note that it is pretty clear from the full schedule that several of the buses don't go all the way to Cannon Beach - in each case the return trip starts 20 minutes after arrival in Manzanita, while Manzanita to Cannon Beach is 25 minutes one way on the schedule. So, only 4 of the 6 buses go beyond Manzanita to Cannon Beach (or can be caught between Cannon Beach and Manzanita going the other way).